# Updating Python 2.7 to 3.9 try: from cStringIO import StringIO except: from StringIO import StringIO

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I've inherited a project in Python 2.7 that needs to be updated to be compatible with Python 3.9 because AWS Lambda has deprecated support for Py 2.7

**The code that needs to be updated to 3.9:**

```python
try:
    from cStringIO import StringIO
except:
    from StringIO import StringIO
```

In AWS Cloudwatch, I usually get an "Unable to Import Module" error, and I think it might be because of this line of code.

**OPTION 1: Should I modify the code so it reads:**

```python
try:
    from io import StringIO
except:
    from io import StringIO
```

**OPTION 2: Should I modify the code so it reads:**

```python
try:
    from io import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from cStringIO import StringIO
```

Comment: For Python 3.x it should be `from io import StringIO`.

Comment: Should I modify the code so it reads:

`try:
    from io import StringIO
except:
    from io import StringIO`

Comment: More or less, but it's best to avoid bare `except:` statements, so I would suggest using something specific like `except ImportError:`

Comment: I can attempt something like `try: from io import StringIO` `except: ImportError:`

Comment: There should be a `from cStringIO import StringIO` following the `except ImportError:` line.

Comment: I've edited my original post. Can you review Option 2 and confirm the syntax is acceptable for Python 3.x

Comment: Option 1 makes no sense, and Option 2 is what I just told you. Let's terminate further discussion.

Comment: Why do you want to retain the ``from cStringIO import StringIO`` line? Do you target Python 3 *only* or both Python 3/2?

Comment: In Python 2, one would try to import the faster `cStringIO` module, falling back to the slower pure-Python module if necessary. In Python 3, there is *only* a single user-facing `io` module. If importing it the first time failed, it would fail the second time as well. (If it *does* fail, that's a problem with your Python installation that is beyond the scope of your script to deal with.)

Comment: My Python 2.7 codebase needs to be updated to Python 3.9. I've learned some of the code was deprecate and the 4 lines of code at the top of my post needs to change to comply with Python 3.9 syntax. My only intention is to retain original functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From user @chepner:
"In Python 2, one would try to import the faster cStringIO module, falling back to the slower pure-Python module if necessary. In Python 3, there is only a single user-facing io module. If importing it the first time failed, it would fail the second time as well. (If it does fail, that's a problem with your Python installation that is beyond the scope of your script to deal with.)"

My final code will read

```python
from io import StringIO
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need in Python 3 is

```
from io import StringIO
```

The `io` module replaces both the `StringIO` and `cStringIO` modules available in Python 2.